# If f is onto, is the inverse one-to-one

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $f$ is onto, is the inverse $f^{-1}$ one-to-one?

Comment: Being onto does not imply being 1-1, which is necessary for $f$ to be invertible.

Comment: Counter example: $D = \{1\}.  f:\mathbb{R}\to D \,: \,f(x) = 1.~ f$ is onto.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. If $f$ is onto, then the inverse $f^{-1}$ may or may not exist.

If the inverse $f^{-1}$ does exist, then $f$ is onto and one-to-one and $f^{-1}$ is onto and one-to-one. (Thus, if we have the inverse there is no need to separately assume that $f$ is onto.)

Conversely, if $f$ is onto and one-to-one, then $f^{-1}$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

Given a function $f:A\to B$, a section of $f$ (id est, a function $g:B\to A$ such that $f\circ g=id_B$) is always injective, because it's the right factor in an injective composition. A section exists only if $f$ is surjective (because $f$ is, in turn, the left factor in a surjective composition). Under the axiom of choice, the latter is an if and only if.

Existence of an inverse, id est of a section $g:B\to A$ such that $g\circ f=id_A$, requires more. Specifically, there is one if and only if $f$ is bijective. This holds regardless of the axiom of choice.

It should be pointed out that the discussion on the existence of an inverse, as interesting as it might be, is something of an idle talk in this instance, because I would evaluate your assertion as "true" in the case where $f$ has no inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Not true. Consider $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = x$.

$f(x)$ is one-to-one since $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $x=y$, but $f^{-1}(x)$ does not exist since some elements like $\frac{1}{2}$ don't have an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}$.